# Using the Title case in an SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, title-case

I have tried various Title Case solutions from here and they give me an `0` in the column. I have to change the `LEN` to `LENGTH` to get it to run. If I strip the statement down to its 2 parts it works.

```
 UPDATE names 
    SET
    surname = UPPER(LEFT(surname, 1)) +
    LOWER(RIGHT(surname, LENGTH(surname) - 1));
```

Or

```
update  names
set     surname = upper(substring(surname,1,1)) + 
        lower(substring(surname, 2, length(surname)-1))
where   length(surname) > 0 ;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: He wants write this: (Before surname : BROWN; after surname: Brown)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why does it put a 0 in the column and not title case the result. I tested on 1000 records and it clobbered all the column data.

Comment: I am using MYSQL on my LocalHost laptop to test before I go live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MySql you must use function CONCAT, to concatenate two strings.

In this way:

```
update  names
set     surname = concat(upper(substring(surname,1,1)),
        lower(substring(surname, 2, length(surname)-1)))
where   length(surname) > 0 ;
```

It's good use `WHERE` condition so you prevent possible nullable field

N.B. Your result is 0 because DBMS tries to sum two number (implicit conversion by your string, so you'll get 0 instead your result).

[Show Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6173e/5/0)

Comment: @PeterBrooks if this did helped you kindly repay the effort given by the answerer thru an upvote or accept

Comment: I've just spent a bit of searching for how to do what in the US we call "Title Case", and I keep finding this "Proper Case" solution on various pages. This solution is shorter that the Proper Case code over here http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=122, but it still seems a bit of a pain that Oracle would make us have to go through all that, and not have a built-in function to just do this in a black-box way. Just sayin.